# WPF ListBox Binding Update

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, listbox

I'm brand new to WPF and I just managed to bind a list of specific class items to a ListBox. The ListBox now successfully displays them. Here's some code, the class first:

```
public class OrderItem
{
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Double Price { get; set; }
}
```

Some dummy data and the binding, which all happens in the constructor of the main program:

```
List<OrderItem> currentOrderItems = new List<OrderItem>();
        currentOrderItems.Add(new OrderItem() { Quantity = 5, Name = "Test", Price = 5 });
        currentOrderItems.Add(new OrderItem() { Quantity = 15, Name = "Test test", Price = 6.66 });
        currentOrderItems.Add(new OrderItem() { Quantity = 1, Name = "Test 3", Price = 15.88 });
        listOrderItems.ItemsSource = currentOrderItems;
```

And the XAML:

```
<ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="150,27,0,23" Name="listOrderItems" Width="150" FontFamily="Times New Roman" FontSize="12">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Margin="4">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Quantity}" FontWeight="Bold"  />
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Name }" />
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Price }" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

My question is how can I update the ListBox to display a new item that I'm adding to the List containing the data a.k.a. the OrderItems. If I add, remove or modify the List in any way, this is not reflected in the ListBox.
Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For your case best way use mvvm patern.
In brief:
Your model OrderItem should implement interface **INotifyPropertyChanged**.
If property changed, it notified about this.
Then create viewmodel and set it in datacontext. In viewModel add **ObservableCollection** with OrderItems, this collection should notified view about changes in it. 
for more information read some articles like this: [MVVM](http://wintellect.com/blogs/jlikness/model-view-viewmodel-mvvm-explained)

Comment: Thank you both for the help!

Comment: Also while binding some dynamic staff, do not forget setting Binding's **NotifyOnSourceUpdated** and **NotifyOnTargetUpdated** properties to `true`

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using a `List<OrderItem>` use `ObservableCollection<OrderItem>`. This will notify that something was added/removed so your ListBox knows to refresh.

Additionally, your `OrderItem` needs to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and your setters need to call `OnPropertyChanged`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also rebind your ListBox in code behind:

```
List<OrderItem> currentOrderItems = new List<OrderItem>();
currentOrderItems.Add(new OrderItem() { Quantity = 5, Name = "Test", Price = 5 });
currentOrderItems.Add(new OrderItem() { Quantity = 15, Name = "Test test", Price = 6.66 });
currentOrderItems.Add(new OrderItem() { Quantity = 1, Name = "Test 3", Price = 15.88 });
```

In code behind:

```
private ObservableCollection<OrderItem> _OrderItemCollection;
public ObservableCollection<OrderItem> OrderItemCollection
{
    get
    {
        if (_OrderItemCollection == null)
            _OrderItemCollection = new ObservableCollection<OrderItem>();
        return _OrderItemCollection;
    }
    set => _OrderItemCollection = value;
}

private CollectionViewSource _OrderItemCollectionViewSource;
public ICollectionView OrderItemCollectionViewSource => _OrderItemCollectionViewSource.View;


public void loadData()
{
    _OrderItemCollectionViewSource = new CollectionViewSource();
    _OrderItemCollectionViewSource.Source = new ObservableCollection<OrderItem>(currentOrderItems) ;
    Binding b = new Binding("OrderItemCollectionViewSource") { Source = this };
    listOrderItems.SetBinding(ListBox.ItemsSourceProperty, b);
}
```

And the XAML:

```
<ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="150,27,0,23" Name="listOrderItems" Width="150" FontFamily="Times New Roman" FontSize="12">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Margin="4">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Quantity}" FontWeight="Bold"  />
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Name }" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Price }" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```