# ListView not updated after adding new items to List

Tags: c#, wpf, list, observablecollection, inotifypropertychanged

I have a `ListView` bounded to a List of a class I created. When doing an operating, it was supposed to add/remove items from the list, but my `ListView` wasn't updated even though I used `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

If I use `ObservableCollection`, it works but I need to have the list sorted, and `ObservableCollection` doesn't do sorting for WPF4.0 :(

Any way I can make the List binding work? Why didn't it work even though I used `INotifyPropertyChanged`?

XAML:

```
<ListView BorderThickness="0" ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedValues, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=OneWay}" Padding="5">
                    <ListView.View>
                        <GridView ColumnHeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource myHeaderStyle}">
                            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Value}"></GridViewColumn>
```

VM:

```
    private List<CheckBoxItem> _selectedValues = new List<CheckBoxItem>();

    public List<CheckBoxItem> SelectedValues
            {
                get { return _selectedValues; }
                set
                {
                    _selectedValues = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }

    private void UnselectValueCommandExecute(CheckBoxItem value)
            {
                value.IsSelected = false;
                SelectedValues.Remove(value);
                //OnPropertyChanged("SelectedValues");
                OnPropertyChanged("IsAllFilteredValuesSelected");
            }

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
```

The `CheckBoxItem` class contains 2 properties, `Value` and `IsChecked`, which I don't think is relevant here.

So basically, I have a button which uses the `UnselectValueCommandExecute` to remove items from the list, and I should see the list updated in the UI, but I'm not.

When I debug, I can see the `SelectedValues` list updated, but not my UI.

Comment: put your code Xaml and VM !

Comment: That depends on how you implemented INotifyPropertyChanged. If you have done it just like any other property, then it will fire when the whole collection object itself has changed, not when its elements are modified.

Comment: Show us your c#-Code with your list. And your XAML would also be great.

Comment: Couldn't this help you? [WPF ListBox Binding Update][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19906911/wpf-listbox-binding-update

Comment: @Deschuytterp As I mentioned, ObservableCollection works for me, but I need it to be sorted on the UI. Unless someone can tell me a quick way to sort it :)

I'll try to post my code here

Comment: It sounds like you are implementing sorting in the viewmodel. depending on what you are trying to do, [sorting can be handled by the view](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745786(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I handle this situation by setting the itemsSource to null and then back to the List, which forces a full refresh, instead of just the NotifyPropertyChanged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `CollectionViewSource` in your UI.

**The XAML**:

```
<Window x:Class="WavTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"    
        xmlns:scm="clr-namespace:System.ComponentModel;assembly=WindowsBase"        
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding TestSource}" x:Key="cvs">
            <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
                <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="Order"/>
            </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
        </CollectionViewSource>
    </Window.Resources>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvs}}" DisplayMemberPath="Description"/>
</Window>
```

**The code behind**:

```
namespace WavTest
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var vm = new ViewModel();
            this.DataContext = vm;

            vm.TestSource.Add(new TestItem { Description="Zero", Order=0 });
        }
    }

    public class ViewModel 
    {
        public ObservableCollection<TestItem> TestSource { get; set; }

        public ViewModel()
        {
            TestSource = new ObservableCollection<TestItem>();
            TestSource.Add(new TestItem { Description = "Second", Order = 2 });
            TestSource.Add(new TestItem { Description = "Third", Order = 3 });
            TestSource.Add(new TestItem { Description = "First", Order = 1 });
        }
    }

    public class TestItem
    {
        public int Order { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Explanation**:

The `ObservableCollection` raises the `PropertyChanged` event as you expect, but you cannot sort it.
So, you need the `CollectionView` to sort it and bind the sorted collection to you `ListView`/`ListBox`.
As you can see, adding an element after the `DataContext` initialization affects the UI sorting the last added item ("Zero") correctly.

Comment: I did try this, but it didn't work for me, I thought I needed IsLiveSortingRequested from WPF4.5. I will try this again.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `ObservableCollection` because this raises a collection changed event which your wpf ListView will pick up on.

How about doing

```
Public ObservableCollection<object> MyList
{
   get 
   {
      return new ObservableCollection<object>(MySortedList);
   }
}
```

and then whenever you change your sorted list raise a property changed event for MyList.

This obviously depends how you would like to sort your list as it might be possible to sort the `ObservableCollection` your question needs more info.

Comment: So, is there any way to raise a collection changed event for list? I guess not?

Comment: nope. You can have 1 list and 1 observablecollection synced to it but I do not think that will be practical.