# ListBox not updating automatically

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I have list that contains many items.I have bound that list to List box A. Every item in list execute sequentially.

For Example: The first item will send command to printer and will get value from printer. I'm using properties to get and set values.So,after getting value in list and I'm taking that value from list and sending to printer. Again I will get value from printer and storing to list. So I want to display response value from printer in list box b whenever printer sends value.

Sending and receiving parameter are automatically handled.

i bound that list to List Box B but i am not getting value.

This is my property.

```
private List<string> rxValuesList;

public List<string> RxValuesList
{
    get
    {
        return rxValuesList;
    }

    set
    {
        SetProperty(ref rxValuesList, value);
    }
}
```

This is my xaml code

```
 <ListBox Name="listboxB" 
 ItemsSource="{Binding  StationProperty.CurrentTestItem.RxValuesList,Mode=TwoWay,
 UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" >
 </ListBox>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WPF ListBox Binding Update](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19906911/wpf-listbox-binding-update)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an `ObservableCollection<string>` instead `List<string>` because `ObservableCollection` will update the UI.

Comment: thanks sir but actually project is very big and too many list are related to this list,because of that i will have to modify so many things. Is there any another solution?

Comment: Maybe, but not a clean one without hacking. I guess you have to spent more time for hacking around then using ObservableCollection including refactoring.